# English phrase for "Don't try to solve too many problems at the same time or you will mess up and have no time for real work"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

I faced a situation where my naive/clueless new boss started to take up all the long-pending internal issues our department had been facing and tried tackling them all at the same time. This caused our main focus to drift from our external clients, because all of our time was consumed preparing reports for solutions.

I asked my colleague what would be the best idiom/phrase for this situation.
He responded that there is probably a phrase "Don't juggle too many balls at the same time". **I thought this was a perfect match for the situation**. But when I Googled it, the search returned no results. I would like to know of an English phrase that describes this situation and is currently in use.

Answer (score 1):

English has a bunch of idioms for this. People have been answering in the comments, which is frowned on on this site, so I'll collect them in an actual answer, and add another one.

One idiom is:

> You've got too many balls in the air. ([See Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+balls+in+the+air).)

Another idiom is:

> You have too much on your plate. ([See Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+lot+on+one%27s+plate).)

A third is:

> You're running off in all directions at once. ([See Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/running+in+all+directions#:%7E:text=all%20rights%20reserved.-,run%20off%20in%20all%20directions,also%20apply%20to%20one%20person.))

Your colleague was clearly trying to remember the first one, but not quite succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

Your "naive/clueless new boss" is **spreading himself/herself too thin."**

**Spread yourself too thin**

> to try to do a lot of different things at the same time, with the result that you cannot do any of them properly

*The company grew too fast and spread itself too thin across too many diverse areas.*

[Collins]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add „run round like a headless chicken“, i.e., "to be very busy doing a lot of things, but in a way that is not very effective" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/run-round-like-a-headless-chicken?topic=busy-and-active) even though it might not be exactly the picture you’re looking for.

Comment: Running around like a headless chicken, to me implies that you're doing things without thinking.

Comment: I agree somewhat, but guess it depends on the perspective. To the chicken, it is probably not too obvious that it does not think; is it to the manager?

Comment: The phrase refers to what it appears like to an outsider. Nothing is obvious to the chicken, since it doesn't have a brain.

Comment: Crazy what this implies for the manager.